How identify people who return within 72 hours of their previous hospital stay?
I'm quite new to R.
I have a database with a unique identifier for each patient (IPP), an identifier for each stay (NDA), and the entry and exit dates for each stay.
I need to identify, for patients who have several stays (several NDAs for the same IPP) who have a stay within 72 hours of discharge from their previous stay.
Problem: I have one line per unique stay (NDA) and not per unique patient (IPP), and I'm not sure how best to proceed to get the desired result.
My database is like this, with 4 columns :
IPP <- c("123456", "456789", "789632","123456", "456789")
NDA <- c("147","211","789","258","456")
entry <- c("01/01/2024", "14/07/2024", "06/06/2024", "08/04/2024", "16/07/2024")
exit <- c("24/02/2024", "15/07/2024", "08/09/2024", "10/04/2024", "20/07/2024")
df <- data.frame(IPP, NDA, entry, exit)
print(df)

I tried to put all the stays of a patient (his NDAs on a single line from the IPP) using pivot_wider. I obtain the data for all the patient's stays on a single line, but with the dates of entry, exit and NDAs following the others. I was thinking of using lubridate next, but I'm not sure that's the best way to proceed and how to manage multiple dates.
BD<- df %>%
  group_by(df$IPP) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(entry, exit, NDA),
          names_from  = id,
          names_prefix = 'id_')`

What I'd like :
  IPP    NDA1      entry1   exit1    NDA2   entry2    exit2    return72h
1 123456 147 01/01/2024  24/02/2024                             no
2 456789 211 14/07/2024  15/07/2024  456 16/07/2024 20/07/2024  yes
3 789632 789 06/06/2024  08/09/2024                             no
4 123456 258 08/04/2024  10/04/2024                             no

Or keep the initial structure of the df and add a tag giving the time between two stays and, if possible, the number of the corresponding dataframe line(s). This solution might be smarter.
Thank you so much for your help !

I like by() for such tasks.
First, re-organising the data.
# `df0` instead of `df`
df0[c("entry", "exit")] = lapply(df0[c("entry", "exit")], as.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
df0 = sort_by(df0, ~IPP+entry+exit)

Applying difftime() via by() and grouping by IPP:
by(df0[-1], list(IPP = df0$IPP), transform, 
   i = difftime(entry, as.Date(c(NA, exit[-length(exit)])), units = "days")) |>
  array2DF() |> `rownames<-`(NULL) # cosmetics 

giving
     IPP NDA      entry       exit       i
1 123456 147 2024-01-01 2024-02-24 NA days
2 123456 258 2024-04-08 2024-04-10 44 days
3 456789 211 2024-07-14 2024-07-15 NA days
4 456789 456 2024-07-16 2024-07-20  1 days
5 789632 789 2024-06-06 2024-09-08 NA days

The row name operation is cosmetics.
With tapply():
df0$i = unlist(tapply(df0[c("entry", "exit")], df0$IPP, 
                      with, 3 > entry - as.Date(c(NA, exit[-length(exit)]))))

giving
     IPP NDA      entry       exit     i
1 123456 147 2024-01-01 2024-02-24    NA
4 123456 258 2024-04-08 2024-04-10 FALSE
2 456789 211 2024-07-14 2024-07-15    NA
5 456789 456 2024-07-16 2024-07-20  TRUE
3 789632 789 2024-06-06 2024-09-08    NA

Might be better to use boolean or factor (here binary) than character to indicate states. I have changed the order here.

Use lag() function from {dplyr} to find previous record:
IPP <- c("123456", "456789", "789632","123456", "456789")
NDA <- c("147","211","789","258","456")
entry <- c("01/01/2024", "14/07/2024", "06/06/2024", "08/04/2024", "16/07/2024")
exit <- c("24/02/2024", "15/07/2024", "08/09/2024", "10/04/2024", "20/07/2024")
df <- data.frame(IPP, NDA, entry, exit)

Let's group by patient (IPP) and calculate the difference between entry and last exit:
df |>
  dplyr::group_by(IPP) |>
  dplyr::mutate(diff = as.Date(entry, "%d/%m/%Y") - as.Date(dplyr::lag(exit, n=1), "%d/%m/%Y"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#> # Groups:   IPP [3]
#>   IPP    NDA   entry      exit       diff   
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <drtn> 
#> 1 123456 147   01/01/2024 24/02/2024 NA days
#> 2 456789 211   14/07/2024 15/07/2024 NA days
#> 3 789632 789   06/06/2024 08/09/2024 NA days
#> 4 123456 258   08/04/2024 10/04/2024 44 days
#> 5 456789 456   16/07/2024 20/07/2024  1 days

Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.0

I think this is easiest with a non-equi join. First I make a version of the data where the dates are encoded in Date format:
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df |>
  mutate(across(entry:exit, lubridate::dmy))

Then I join the data to itself, linking wherever the IPP matches, the next entry follows the current exit, but the shifted-back version of the next entry precedes the current exit.
df2 |>
  left_join(df2 |> mutate(entry_back = entry - 3),
            join_by(IPP, exit < entry, exit >= entry_back))

Result
     IPP NDA.x    entry.x     exit.x NDA.y    entry.y     exit.y entry_back
1 123456   147 2024-01-01 2024-02-24  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2 456789   211 2024-07-14 2024-07-15   456 2024-07-16 2024-07-20 2024-07-13
3 789632   789 2024-06-06 2024-09-08  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4 123456   258 2024-04-08 2024-04-10  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
5 456789   456 2024-07-16 2024-07-20  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>


In this solution, you can cluster multiple events occurring within 72 hours and have a column that refers to linked NDAs.
It does so by clustering events using as a distance function the time in days between entry and exit. By using the complete linkage, all the events included in a cluster must happen within a 72-hour span. You could use the single linkage instead to cluster together events whose individual distance are less or equal to 72 hours.
df |>
    mutate(across(c(entry, exit), ~as.Date(.x, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))) |>
    group_by(IPP) |>
    mutate(clusteredEvents = if (n() > 1)
                   {
                       clustIds <- outer(entry, exit, "-") |>
                           as.dist() |>
                           hclust(method = "complete") |>
                           cutree(h = 3)
                       
                       linkedNDA <- ave(NDA, clustIds, FUN = list) |>
                           purrr::map(unique) |>
                           purrr::map(paste, collapse = ",") |>
                           unlist()
                       
                       linkedNDA[clustIds]
                   } else 
                       NDA
           )

## Groups:   IPP [3]
#  IPP    NDA   entry      exit       clusteredEvents
#  <chr>  <chr> <date>     <date>     <chr>          
#1 123456 147   2024-01-01 2024-02-24 147            
#2 456789 211   2024-07-14 2024-07-15 211,456        
#3 789632 789   2024-06-06 2024-09-08 789            
#4 123456 258   2024-04-08 2024-04-10 258            
#5 456789 456   2024-07-16 2024-07-20 211,456        

